# How to convert ArrayBuffer from SubtleCrypto.sign to a string

Tags: javascript, browser, cryptography, arraybuffer

I am working on a project that needs to deal with crypto on the client side.
We generate a private/public key pair. In the client side we use the crypto key to create a signature for every payload we send to server.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description
const arrayBufferInUniCode = stringToArrayBufferInUnitCode("foo");

const signatureArrayBuffer = await SubtleCrypto.sign({name: "HMAC",hash: { name: "SHA-256"}}, {private key}, arrayBufferInUniCode);
```

But seems like the array buffer returned from `sign` is not in unicode format. If I try to process it as defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description to try to turn it into a string, it doesn't work -- it doesn't contains the right bytes sequence.

Any idea how to process the array buffer from the `sign` function

Comment: Why not just use HTTPS for the transfer?

Answer (score 1):

Encryption is binary and arbitrary binary is not valid unicode. Thus the encrypted output is not generally unicode.

Just save as binary or if a character encoding is needed convert the encrypted data to ASCII using Base64 encoding. On decryption convert back to binary prior to decryption.

Comment: If I convert the array buffer to ASCII then do base64 will I lost data? Since the original array buffer is in Unicode

Comment: You do not convert to ASCII and then Base64, you convert the binary (buffer) directly to Base64. Base64 is a lossless encoding. Some encryption implementations include Base64 encoding and decoding as an option.

Comment: native btoa does not take array buffer directly. Let me look around see if there is any library for it. Will be good if you can share one

Comment: I am not fully follow, can you share a sample how you can convert an array buffer to a string that can be recover back later. I have a ArrayBuffer that is constructed follow the unicode convention.  i don't see how it will work.